# How to use the Office 365 profile hover card (defaultHoverField) without a person column

Tags: sharepoint-online, person, default, hover-panel

On my Sharepoint List, I want to store different team members in something like a text column instead of a person column so that I can handle inactive users or users who have left the organization, while still keeping the default hover effect with the full persona card by using column formatting via defaultHoverField. Is there any way to achieve this?
(eg. by mimicking the person field data in array ["Id": "...",
"AccountEnabled": true,...] to work with defaultHoverField)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own cards on hover via [Column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#custom-cards-on-hover).

Of course, you can drop several functions like "Update your profile" or "Show more". But I don’t think you can get “full persona card” since the default Profile card works only with *Person or Group* column when using `defaultHoverField`.

You can see an example here to build a custom card on hover:
http://www.ktskumar.com/2020/04/extend-sharepoint-columns-using-custom-card-json/